# Core Data + Cloudkit works in development but doesn't work on production after distributed

Tags: macos, core-data, icloud, cloudkit

I followed directions in [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/setting_up_core_data_with_cloudkit), enabled Cloudkit, selected a container, figured out the database index and deployed the schema to production. During development, the app has been syncing fine to Cloudkit's private database. However, once I uploaded it to the app store & tested it via TestFlight then I noticed my app is not syncing to Cloudkit. Checked all the databases within the container and it's not getting any activity.

Am I missing any critical setup steps to enable the database for production?

Answer (score 1):

A common error is to not have the "CloudKit" or some other capability enabled for your "Release" build.  When you test through Test Flight, you are typically using the Release build for the first time.

The "Signing and Capabilities" UI for the project in Xcode has an "All"/"Debug"/Release tab, and it is not obvious when your release settings differ from your Debug settings.

Comment: Could be it. But some screens and code are nice to better troubleshoot your problem. Refer to: https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct to write better questions.

Answer (score 1):

Visit [CloudKit console](https://icloud.developer.apple.com/). From your **CloudKit Database,** select **Deploy Schema Changes**. And then click on **Deploy**. That's it. Data will synchronise fine in production build too.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and found an [Apple Dev Forum thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/717838) that solved it:

Add CloudKit.framework to be included in the app target's "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content" section (with the "Do not Embed" option).